# Android phone not displaying SMS sender ID

Tags: sms

My Android phone does not show SMS sender ID, for example if one of the friends from my contact list, texts me, my phone will not show the name of the sender (which is saved in my contact list), it just shows the phone numner of the sender.
But when they call me, my phone shows the caller ID name (as saved in my contact list).
Any help fixing this issue will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Did you revoke Contacts permission from your default SMS app? Verify that permission in the Settings app. Which SMS app are you using? Did this issue start occurring only recently or has it been the case since the time you bought your phone?

Comment: Try clearing the cache of the SMS app //If that doesn't help, change the SMS app to establish of the problem is with app or elsewhere

Comment: @Firelod Yes, I did the permissions are given (both SMS and contacts)

Answer (score 1):

1. GO to settings
2. Try to find somthing like  Apps/ Application manager / Applications in settings home.
3. Open it, you'll see a list of apps.
4. locate your SMS app from that  list
5. go to permissions and give access to contact permissions

regards.

Comment: @ karthik nair Thanks for the response. I already did check the permission as you explained. Permissions are given to the app, but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. In settings, search for Sync (google contact sync), enable it. That will fix the problem.

Comment: glad that you fixed.