# SMS sender ID does not identify inbound SMS numbers with (9)

Tags: sms, caller-id

I live in Argentina.
Whenever I receive a phone call from *+54 11 xxxx-xxxx* and I have that number associated with *Roger* in my contacts, *Roger* is identified.
But if I don't pick up for whatever reason, I get an SMS reporting the missed call.
The number which originates the SMS is reported as *+54 9 11 xxxx-xxxx*, and *Roger* is not identified.
If I add *+54 9 11 xxxx-xxxx* as a number for *Roger*, the SMS ID is correctly updated, which confirms the SMS app has access to my contacts. I shouldn't need replicating the number for all my contacts.

Currently using Android 11, Samsung S10e.

This was working fine in my previous Android 8, Samsung J7 prime, prior to my *Smart Switch*.

See details below.

**How can I fix this?**

After trying [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/241533/android-phone-not-displaying-sms-sender-id#comment321096_241533) I realized the problem was the extra *9*.
I didn't try syncing numbers stored in the phone with my Google account [as here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/241559/81584) (and I am not sure my problem is the same as that other). SMS ID should not rely on Google, and I didn't need that with Android 8. I guess the OS (or the app?) should take care of that.
([related](https://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/1030887-android-phone-not-displaying-sms-sender-id.html#post6981769))

---

### More details

#### How this was working before the phone switch

I was using a Samsung J7 prime with Android 8, with the same sim card and mobile provider as I use now.
I am right now checking in my old phone a message that I received, with number *+54 9 11 xxxx-xxxx*, and SMS ID is correct.
The same message, in my new phone (transferred via Smart Switch) is not SMS-IDentified.

#### How are phone numbers built

Phone numbers are built as *+(Country) (Area) (Number)* as usual, with a possible extra *9* after the country code, or a possible extra *15* after the area code.
The historical reasons for those extra numbers, and when were they mandatory (calling from abroad/within Argentina, phone call/SMS, calling from mobile/landline, calling to mobile/landline, etc.) are a separate issue. These rules kept confusing people, in particular foreigners. Nowadays **networks are smart enough**, the rules are *mostly* (I wouldn't dare saying 100%) not needed. You could also use *+(Country) (Area) (No.)* from within Argentina; before, that was not allowed, *0(Area) (No.)* was needed from within Argentina. I am not certain, but I think even *(Area) (No.)* works. This is similar to what happens in other countries.
Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Argentina#Inbound_SMS

So if I call using *+54 9 11 xxxx-xxxx*, it will likely work well, the same as if I use  *+54 11 xxxx-xxxx* or *011 xxxx-xxxx*.

54: Argentina 
9: Prefix for mobile numbers 
11: Buenos Aires 
xxxx-xxxx: phone number

Then there is the issue of Caller / SMS ID for inbound calls and messages.

Comment: I would contact your mobile network provider. If a person is calling in with one number then this number should also be used for the missed-call-SMS (which is generated by your MNO). So if you see two different numbers then this is bad, even if for historical reasons both numbers are practically identical if you would try to call them.

Comment: @Robert - It might be the case that the MNO is handling the phone numbers. But I am certain the phone/OS/app has its part, see my edited OP, under **How this was working before the phone switch**.
And I heard of no one here with this problem, so I guess there should be a much simpler solution than going through the thorns of a MNO.